# BitmapFactory cannot decode an image

Tags: android, base64, android-bitmap, fileoutputstream, bitmapfactory

In a React Native app for Android, I am trying to write an image (passed as base64) onto the filesystem and later decode it using BitmapFactory.

Why is BitmapFactory still unable to decode the image after using (Base64.decode) while storing it?

The error:

> Cannot decode bitmap:
>   file:///data/data/com.reactnativeapp/files/rct-image-store/1

The custom written method storing the image:

```
  @ReactMethod
  public void addImageFromBase64(String base64_image_data, Callback successCallback, Callback failureCallback){
    String imageStorageDir = this.reactContext.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/rct-image-store/";
    String file_uri = imageStorageDir+"1";
    try {
      File f = new File(imageStorageDir);
      if(!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdir();
      }
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file_uri, false);
      byte[] decodedImage = Base64.decode(base64_image_data, Base64.DEFAULT);
      fos.write(decodedImage);
      fos.close();
      successCallback.invoke("file://"+file_uri);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      failureCallback.invoke("Failed to add image from base64String"+ioe.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      failureCallback.invoke("Failed to add image from base64String"+e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Shortened method for accessing the image (`fullResolutionBitmap` is `null`):

```
InputStream inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(uri));;
BitmapFactory.Options outOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap fullResolutionBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, outOptions);/// fullResolutionBitmap==null
```

Here is the image, the bottom part looks cropped. Since both original and converted image have the grey area, the problem seems to be not with the conversion of the image, but with the source (camera).

Original image:

[image: Original image]

Converted image:

[image: Converted image]

Comment: I recommend calling `fos.flush()`, then `fos.getFD().sync()`, before `fos.close()`. Beyond that, copy the image file from your emulator and see if it looks OK on your development machine.

Comment: I don't know what "Android File Transfer" is. You are writing to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (`getFilesDir()`), which is not directly accessible on production hardware by most tools.

Comment: Can't run the command `adb shell run-as 'com.reactnativeapp' cp /data/data/com.reactnativeapp/files/rct-image-store/ ./APPDATA`, despite setting `android:debuggable="true"`. Perhaps I don't have enough rights, `/data/system/packages.list` on my Android is set to `-rw-r-----`.

Comment: Well, `./APPDATA` is unlikely to be someplace that you can use. Try copying to external storage (`/storage/emulated/0`, `/sdcard`, etc.).

Comment: I uploaded the image and it looks like the grey area is the source of this error. Maybe FileOutputStream buffer issue?

Comment: "Maybe FileOutputStream buffer issue?" -- possibly, which is why I suggested calling `fos.flush()`, then `fos.getFD().sync()`, before `fos.close()`. You could write the base64 string on its own out to a file, copy that from your device, decode it on your development machine, and see what you get. If the corruption is there, then the problem is in the string itself or the image the string was built from. If the corruption is not there, the problem is in the decode or in writing the results of the decode to the file.

Comment: The error:

`Cannot decode bitmap: file:///data/data/com.reactnativeapp/files/rct-image-store/1`. There is no statement in your code that can produce that error.

Comment: The error is is result of `fullResolutionBitmap==null`. Yes I omitted a lot of unnecessary code in the method for accessing the image because the problem is in the method for storing.

Comment: No that is not the reason for the error. And of course you should show the code that produces the error. What else?